# DB query to read an object inside array list

Tags: kotlin, cassandra, scylla

[Look at The Image where we see the item_number and quantity where **i only need item_number not the quantity**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vtb9h.png)I am trying to run a query to read or get item_numbers which is inside items(Array List) tried so many ways but it don't worked.

Comment: Please include the text of the query you are trying to run.

Comment: select item.item_number FROM planning.consumption_forecast WHERE location_number = 101 and business_date = '2019-09-17' Allow Filtering